# SQL command to calculate from Amount and ID, total weight

Tags: sql

Table: orderproducts

```
orderid   quantity       weight
-----------------------------------
4           5             0.1
4           2             0.5
5           3             2.5
5           7             0.9
```

1) With the following SQL command, the total weight is calculated correctly, but product quantity is Ignored. How can I expand my SQL command to query the quantity of product?

```
select orderid, sum (weight) as totalweight from orderproducts group by orderid
```

Now I have for ORDERID 4 the value (totalweight) => 0.6

Must correctly => 1.5

2) In addition, I would like the SQL command to "WHERE" (where other_table.status = "finish") extend from another table. It also does not work. :-(

```
select orderid, sum (weight) as totalweight from orderproducts where other_table.status = "finish" group by orderid
```

Comment: Do you know about Joins (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: @rafig, where is product quantity stored? Please edit your question to add any other relevant tables/columns.

Comment: Ramblin amount == quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT orderid,
       SUM(weight*quantity) AS totalweight
FROM orderproducts AS a
JOIN othertable AS b ON (b.orderid=b=id)
WHERE b.status = "finish"
GROUP BY orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1)For amount of product:

```
select orderid,sum (amount) as totalamount, sum (weight) as totalweight 
   from orderproducts group by orderid
```

2) You cannot put some other table into the where clause of the table in the current query unless you put a sub-query in it. Try this:

```
select orderid, sum (weight) as totalweight from orderproducts where orderid in 
   (select orderid from other_table where other_table .status = "finish")
group by orderid
```

Comment: when calculating the total weight must involve product quantity.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
select orderid,sum (amount) as totalamount, sum (weight) as totalweight from orderproducts group by orderid
```

2)
  you must use join

```
  select orderid, sum (weight*quantity) as totalweight from orderproducts as a join othertable AS b on (b.orderid=b=id) where b.status = "finish" group by orderid
```

Comment: when calculating the total weight must involve product quantity.
Now I have for ORDERID 4 the value (totalweight) => 0.6

Must correctly => 1.5